# CSS3 not working with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I ran into a bit of a problem with bootstrap and css3. Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(132deg, #ec5218, #1665c1);
      background-size: 400% 400%;
      animation: BackgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes BackgroundGradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }
    }
    
    h1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 2em;
      background-color: #000;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Mitchell Smith</h1>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the problem, so with this block of code everything works fine, my body has a gradient background and everything is working. Now when I link bootstrap using

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

all of my css goes away. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Fiddle would be good.

Comment: Link bootstrap before your css, `<link ..bootstrap/> <link ..you-css-file/>`, this way your style will override bootstrap's'.

Comment: Just copy and paste his code....

Comment: It may be possible you are including bootstrap library after yours. Try to include your code at the last. If this is not the case then try to demonstrate your work somewhere.

Comment: @MrGeek tried linking the bootstrap before my css and the styling of my h1 is working but the gradient still isn't showing up. But if I don't link the bootstrap the animated gradient works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

For you to understand the problem: The last css rule for each items is the one that is actually applied. If you link the other css files before, your individual code would overwrite the other.
Also if you have multiple rules for an items in a single Stylesheet, only the most bottom one is applied. (If they have the same attribute targeted)

Answer (score 1):

Put the boostrap link right above your style tag. That will do.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(132deg, #ec5218, #1665c1);
            background-size: 400% 400%;
            animation: BackgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
        }
...
```

Comment: Almost. The background will be white because the only element is absolute-positioned, and the `body` no longer has default margin (due to Bootstrap). Adding some content or `html, body { height: 100%; }` would fix it.

Comment: I went ahead and added the link directly above the style tag and I'm running into the same problem, the h1 styling is working but the gradient is gone. Does it have to do with bootstraps body styling interfering with my css?

Comment: It works perfectly on my web browser. Google Chrome. Which web browser do you use?

Comment: @JonUleis Thank you! That did the trick, I was so stuck on fixing that one problem that I oversaw the fact that the only element was absolute-positioned. Once adding some more content the gradient is now showing!