# why this css animation not working?

Tags: css

Could you please tell me why the animation is not working in this code?

```css
.allTopics {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3300, #cc00cc);
  animation: topicBackground 10s ease infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes topicBackground {
  0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;}
  50%  { background-position: 100% 50%;}
  100% { background-position: 0% 50%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes topicBackground {
   0%   { background-position: 0% 50%;}
  50%  { background-position: 100% 50%;}
  100% { background-position: 0% 50%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="allTopics"></div>
```

The goal is to make the div have gradient background and animate between the 2 colours back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to animate the `background-position` but that won't work with a linear gradient. It's not an image, therefore it doesn't have a `background-position`.

Unfortunately there's no straight-forward way to animate gradients in CSS, but you can check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759) for workarounds.

**EDIT**

After discussion in the comment you can apparently make this work by using the `background-size` property with a value that's above 100%, like `background-size: 400% 400%`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Using background-position works here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084985/css3-not-working-with-bootstrap/46085061?noredirect=1#comment79132457_46085061
Is it because background-position only works for body, not a div?

Comment: @vietnguyen No that's because they're using `background-size: 400% 400%` which is a neat little hack I wasn't aware of!

Comment: even with that, this code still doesn't work (I've tried). I wonder why.

Comment: @vietnguyen It does, look at [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrpnf13y/).

Comment: Yes, it does. Somehow I didn't even notice the change. Thank you.